# Is there a way to find out the timestamp of a packet when it left the source server?

Tags: networking, packet, tcpdump, packet-capture

I am running a tcpdump on my server and capturing the data . I don't have access to the source server .
I can find the timestamp of the packet when it hits the NIC of the server where i am running tcpdump.
I would like to know if there a way to find out the timestamp when packets left the source server ?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if there a way to find out the timestamp when packets left the source server ?

Yes - have somebody run tcpdump (or Wireshark or some other sniffer) on the source server.  You can't determine that by capturing on some other machine.

Also bear in mind that sniffing on the source server will tell you when the packet reached the point in the networking stack when the packet gets handed to the packet capture mechanism; that's not necessarily the time when the packet is transmitted on the network.